# Not able to add entries for System JRE settings in windows 7

Tags: applet, java, jnlp

- I have both `jdk1.6` and `jdk1.7` installed in windows 7.
- Added both the entries in Java Control Panel, JRE Settings , under User tab.
- And enabled 1.7 version.

I want my browsers use version 1.7 for applet/jnlp. But it is still using version 1.6 (which i have disabled in java control panel, under User tab) in the browser.

Note, the entry under System tab points to version 1.6 and im not able to edit/remove it.

I dont want to uninstall jdk1.6, how to change the System entry or tell browsers to use jdk1.7 instead jdk1.6 for applet/jnlp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a .jnlp file on your machine (Create an empty file)
- Right click on it and click on Open With
- Now select $JAVA_HOME/bin/javaws.exe

It should solve your problem. (It is the simplest solution that comes to my mind)

Problem must be in Window registry. Registry is set to JDK 6.